# JSON missing dictionary (mantle)

Tags: objective-c, json, github-mantle

I'm trying to conver this JSON to a model:

```
  [
    {
        "status": "Top-up done",
        "amount": "25.00",
        "amount_ex_vat": "20.66",
        "executed_on": "2014-07-28 20:21:33",
        "method": "Bancontact/Mister Cash",
        "payment_received_on": "2014-07-28 20:21:29"
    },
    {
        "status": "Top-up done",
        "amount": "15.00",
        "amount_ex_vat": "12.40",
        "executed_on": "2014-05-26 19:41:36",
        "method": "PayPal",
        "payment_received_on": "2014-05-26 19:41:31"
    },
    {
        "status": "Top-up done",
        "amount": "10.00",
        "amount_ex_vat": "8.26",
        "executed_on": "2014-02-26 20:43:39",
        "method": "PayPal",
        "payment_received_on": "2014-02-26 20:43:35"
    },
    {
        "status": "Top-up done",
        "amount": "15.00",
        "amount_ex_vat": "12.40",
        "executed_on": "2014-01-18 12:43:09",
        "method": "PayPal",
        "payment_received_on": "2014-01-18 12:43:06"
    }
]
```

This is my class:

```
@interface TopupHistory : MTLModel 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * amount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * executed_on;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * method;
@end

@implementation TopupHistory

(NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey { return @{ @"amount": @"amount", @"executed_on": @"executed_on", @"method": @"method", }; } @end
```

Thought if I named the vars exactly the same it wouldn't be necessary to implement JSONKeyPath but I did.

And this is my method to convert:

```
-(void) convertFrom:(id) responseObject toModel:(Class) model resultBlock: (NetworkBlock)resultBlock
{
NSError * didFail;
id result = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:model fromJSONDictionary:responseObject error:&didFail];
if (!didFail) {
resultBlock(result,nil);
}
else
{
NSLog(@"Couldn't convert app infos JSON to model: %@", didFail);
resultBlock(nil,didFail);
}
}
```

where model is my classname and responseObject is just a id object I filled with AFNetworking.

I'm always getting this error:

```
Domain=MTLJSONAdapterErrorDomain Code=3 "Missing JSON dictionary" UserInfo=0x913a690 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=TopupHistory could not be created because an invalid JSON dictionary was provided: __NSCFArray, NSLocalizedDescription=Missing JSON dictionary}
2014-07-29 13:11:55.780 test Info[10953:60b] Missing JSON dictionary
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON, but like NSLog of an *array* of NSDictionaries.

Comment: I just printed the AFNetworking responseObject like this  NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

Comment: I've edited my post with the raw JSON data from the website.

Comment: Check responseObject's class. I bet it's NSArray, while `+ (id)modelOfClass:(Class)modelClass fromJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary error:(NSError **)error` expects NSDictionary.

Comment: Jup you were right. Thanks for pointing me on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You response is an array of dictionaries, so you should use the [MTLJSONAdapter method modelsOfClass:fromJSONArray:error:](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/blob/1547358dbaf927c62c99922f3159034ef3561c84/Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.h#L107) to convert them to an array of Mantle models.

Your code should be changed as below:

```
-(void) convertFrom:(id) responseObject toModel:(Class) model resultBlock: (NetworkBlock)resultBlock
{
NSError * didFail;
id result = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:model fromJSONArray:responseObject error:&didFail];
//...
```

Comment: I had it to via Kreiri pointing me on that it was an array. Thanks :)

Comment: Good stuff. Hopefully this helps someone else out in the future too :)